# Angular-Meteor + Ionic: How to decide between Meteor CLI and Ionic CLI?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I'm about to start a project using Meteor, Angular and Ionic as explained in [the Angular-Meteor tutorials](https://angular-meteor.com/). However, there are two versions of the tutorial, one using the [Meteor CLI](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/setup) and one using the [Ionic CLI](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup). I have to decide, which CLI to use for the upcoming project, but could not find information about each's pros and cons. So far, I have worked on the Ionic-CLI tutorial which also seems to be more up-to-date than the other. But I guess, this does not mean this approach is also generally better.

So,

- Are there differences between the two CLIs to be considered before a new project?
- What are the pros and cons of using the Meteor CLI?
- And what are the pros and cons of using the Ionic CLI instead?
- Can one say, when to use the one or the other approach or is it just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 4):

that's a very good question.
As always, the answer for your last question is yes - it is a matter of taste, but I will try to expand a bit anyway.

Predicting the future in the Javascript world is very hard or even impossible to do, so I'll just share some thoughts.

All of those CLIs were mocked by the crowd at some point or another, but they all established themselves very well throughout time.

The Meteor CLI is here since 2011, before all of the current tools were even thought about, but through visionary thinking, in 2017, is still relevant, the easiest to use and is making amazing work to keep being up to date with everything that is happening in the Javascript world and innovate on top of it.

At the beginning the Angular CLI started as a very small and weird project (who needs another CLI) but today it is great for the community, it provides great stability and is now a great place to push innovations to the Angular Community (the ABC project, easy SW support, semantics, etc...)

The Ionic CLI, like the Meteor CLI is also trying to help with wrapping Cordova and shipping mobile apps.

Currently, I would recommend to an Angular developer to start with the Angular CLI.  it's just how the Angular community works right now - anything that the Angular team decides to endorse, is becoming the safe standard, whether it's good or not.
That's why I think currently Ionic is a less safe choice, not because their UI or CLI are not good, but because the majority of the community will prefer to use Angular Material and AngularCLI, no matter the actual differences.
I believe that's why Ionic is pushing to become relevant outside of the Angular community, it has become a hard environment to innovate outside of the core team (but I believe the Angular team is working to change that).

But, who knows what will happen in the future?  here are some possibilities:

Meteor is an amazing company, they proved themselves as people who can see the future with a very clear vision.
That's why their Javascript platform vision is still as relevant as ever, that's why they became the industry leader in GraphQL which in my opinion probably the safest choice of tech in your stack going forward.
That means they have the resources and community leadership to keep innovating and making the Meteor CLI even easier and more standard across the whole Javascript community.

I could keep writing so much but I think I should stop.

I would recommend to go with the AngularCLI for now, integrate Apollo and GraphQL as your API layer as much as possible and keep an eye on Meteor, as my answer here will become outdated in 6 months :) as Meteor would release their next versions and Angular would try to go with the ABC project

Comment: Wow, this is more complicated than I expected :D